# Form an array from the for-loop

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop in which I am getting all the values one by one but I need to form those values into one array.

Can any one let me know how to get form all the values into one array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < marray.length; i++) {
    mId = marray[i].id;
    var yourArray = [];
    yourArray.push(marray);
    console.log(marray);
}
```

Output getting from the above code is : `["0123"] and ["3456"]`

```
But the expected output is ["0123","3456"]
```

Comment: just put var yourArray = []; before starting for loop

Comment: @Kermani How would that help?

Comment: each is like foreach() in php, i think it is maybe  helpful for you

Comment: You don't need to declare the array inside the loop. Declare it before the start of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works fine, Is there any other method to reduce the code because I have two for loops, it just looping all the time, once the value is present the loop should break there itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a new `yourArray` for each loop iteration. Instead of doing that, create it just once before starting the loop:

```
var yourArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < marray.length; i++) {
    mId = marray[i].id;
    yourArray.push(mId);
}
```

Note that I have changed the code to read `yourArray.push(mId)` because from the question it seems that's what you want -- not `yourArray.push(marray)`.

A more compact way of doing the same is to use the array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function like this:

```
var yourArray = marray.map(function(row) { return row.id; });
```

This last version won't work out of the box in IE 8, so if you care about that you need to take appropriate measures.

Comment: I tried using .map but it is not working. could you please help me out

Comment: @user1853128: If it doesn't work for you then you are making some error. Please post a new question explaining what you did, what you expected and what happened instead. People who are available will answer.

Comment: Thank you jon, inorder to break the statement once the loop is done should I use return false or break.

Comment: @user1853128: What does "break the statement" mean? Again, I can't tell what you are asking exactly because there is only a very vague description. Please use the appropriate terminology and ask proper full questions when you are unsure about something.

Answer (score 0):

decalare variable in outside for loop..

```
  var yourArray = [];


     for (var i = 0; i < marray.length; i++) {
                    mId = marray[i].id;
                    yourArray.push(mid);

                }
 console.log(yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise `yourArray` before the loop

Try this

```
var yourArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < marray.length; i++) {
    mId = marray[i].id;
    yourArray.push(mId);
}
```

Comment: i didn't have downvoted, but using `for...in` for arrays isn't a good practice for sequential looping over arrays. You should use `for` in that situation. Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/2412895) for answer.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

The `var yourArray` is initialized to null each time you enter the loop. Define it outside loop.